# Trouble with Windows Persistent Routes

Tags: windows, windows-10

Ok... so playing with dual-homed "admin" devices connected to the leading and OOBM networks. In theory fairly simple; I cannot get routing to work, and I have tried every combination I can think of. What am I missing?

I have a route to the 10.69.4.0/24 network via the 10.69.12.1 gateway, which is a lower metric than the default route.

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
  3...40 b0 76 9e a3 a9 ......Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V - VLAN : Home Network
 16...40 b0 76 9e a3 a9 ......Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V - VLAN : Management
 11...40 b0 76 9e a3 a9 ......Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V - VLAN : DMZ-MGT
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 22...00 15 5d bc 1b 11 ......Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1    192.168.0.128    336
       10.69.12.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      10.69.12.253    281
     10.69.12.253  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.69.12.253    281
     10.69.12.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.69.12.253    281
       10.69.32.0    255.255.255.0       10.69.32.1    192.168.0.128    155
       10.69.32.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      10.69.32.253    281
     10.69.32.253  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.69.32.253    281
     10.69.32.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.69.32.253    281
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      172.20.48.0    255.255.240.0         On-link       172.20.48.1   5256
      172.20.48.1  255.255.255.255         On-link       172.20.48.1   5256
    172.20.63.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       172.20.48.1   5256
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.0.128    336
    192.168.0.128  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.128    336
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.128    336
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.0.128    336
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      10.69.32.253    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      10.69.12.253    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       172.20.48.1   5256
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.128    336
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.69.32.253    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.69.12.253    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       172.20.48.1   5256
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
       10.69.32.0    255.255.255.0       10.69.32.1      75
       10.69.12.0    255.255.255.0       10.69.12.1      75
        10.69.2.0    255.255.255.0       10.69.12.1      75
        10.69.4.0    255.255.255.0       10.69.12.1      75
       10.69.10.0    255.255.255.0       10.69.12.1      75
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1  Default
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  3    281 ::/0                     fe80::3eec:efff:fec5:5c3
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
  3    281 2600:4040:264c:d710::/64 On-link
  3    281 2600:4040:264c:d710::110c/128
                                    On-link
  3    281 fe80::/64                On-link
 16    281 fe80::/64                On-link
 11    281 fe80::/64                On-link
 22   5256 fe80::/64                On-link
  3    281 fe80::a28:924:efc9:45a5/128
                                    On-link
 11    281 fe80::289d:859b:8b90:b3c7/128
                                    On-link
 16    281 fe80::396d:bc1c:b90f:d06c/128
                                    On-link
 22   5256 fe80::d858:c88:4ea4:2e0a/128
                                    On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
  3    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
 16    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
 11    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
 22   5256 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

C:\Windows\system32>route print

C:\Windows\system32>tracert 10.69.4.9

Tracing route to 10.69.4.9 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.0.1
  2    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.69.4.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Fun Fact, the "interface IDs" to use are the ones listed in the first column at the very top of route print, not what is listed in IPConfig. Not sure why they are different but hopefully this helps someone else.